# How to find and replace all occurrences of a json dictionary in json file using Python?

Tags: python, json, regex, parsing

I am trying to replace all occurrences of the following json dictionary in a json file with another dictionary:

dictionary to be replaced

```
{
   "AP": {
           "UFD": xxx,
           "DF": "xxxxxx"
         },
   "IE": xxxx,
   "$": "PDAE"
}
```

dictionary to be replaced with

```
{
   "FileNameModifierItemPosition": 1,
   "FileNameModifierItemType": 0,
   "FileNameModifierParameters": {
                                  "DateParameters": {
                                                      "DT": 0,
                                                      "UFD": true,
                                                      "DF": "yyyyMMdd"
                                                    },
                                  "FqlParameters":  {
                                                      "FExpression": null
                                                    }
                                 },
    "IE": true,
    "$": "PDMFN
}
```

but I wanna be able to parse the dictionary to be replaced and extract the values of IE, UFD, DF and assign to the corressponding fields in the second dictionary. How can I accomplish this in Python using regex?

Comment: The first dictionary already contains valid data for those fields you want.  I don't see what you mean when you say you want to 'extract' them.  You can just assign the values to the fields in the new dictionary, something along the lines of `d2['UF'] = d1['UF']`.  Where does regex come into it?

Comment: From your example, it's not clear for the corresponding fields between first and second dictionary. Are those like `"FqlParameters"`, `"DateParameters"`, and ` "FileNameModifierItemPosition"`, etc are new?

Comment: so the first dictionary is nested in a deep nested json, I want to be able to replace all occurences of the first dictionary using string matching with the other dictionary.

Comment: @PaulCornelius : The regex steps in the way that the values for the corressponding keys in the dictionary can be different.

Comment: Then, to make your question clear, I suggest you change those non-fixed values to something like `xxx`.

Comment: sure yeah lemme do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Please try this approach:

```
import re
# pattern to get values of UFD, DF, and IE from dict1
p1 = '(?s){\s+"AP":\s+{\s+"UFD":\s+(.*?),\s+"DF":\s+"(.*?)"\s+},\s+"IE":\s+(.*?),\s+"\$":\s+"PDAE"\s+}'
# pattern to match dict2
p2 = '({[\s\S]+?"UFD":\s+)(.*?)(,\s+"DF":\s+")(.*?)("[\s\S]+?"IE":\s+)(.*?)(,[\s\S]+?})'

dict1 = """
{
   "AP": {
           "UFD": xxx,
           "DF": "xxxxxx"
         },
   "IE": xxxx,
   "$": "PDAE"
}
"""

dict2 = """
{
   "FileNameModifierItemPosition": 1,
   "FileNameModifierItemType": 0,
   "FileNameModifierParameters": {
                                  "DateParameters": {
                                                      "DT": 0,
                                                      "UFD": true,
                                                      "DF": "yyyyMMdd"
                                                    },
                                  "FqlParameters":  {
                                                      "FExpression": null
                                                    }
                                 },
    "IE": true,
    "$": "PDMFN
}
"""
# retrieve values from dict1
dict1_values = re.findall(p1, dict1)[0]
# replace dict2 with corressponding values from dict1
print re.sub(p2, r'\1%s\3%s\5%s\7' % dict1_values, dict2)
```

Output:

```
{
   "FileNameModifierItemPosition": 1,
   "FileNameModifierItemType": 0,
   "FileNameModifierParameters": {
                                  "DateParameters": {
                                                      "DT": 0,
                                                      "UFD": xxx,
                                                      "DF": "xxxxxx"
                                                    },
                                  "FqlParameters":  {
                                                      "FExpression": null
                                                    }
                                 },
    "IE": xxxx,
    "$": "PDMFN
}
```

Comment: I think it doesn't take into account the values of the individual key values like xxxx.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for. [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO2tK5/3)

Comment: dude you are my savior, thanks a lot for such a good answer, however I used a little different approach as to how to update different occurences of the pattern with different values. Thanks anyways